# Proving or disproving: $P\left(\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}<\frac{U_2S_2+c\bar{U_2}T_2}{U_1S_1+c\bar{U_1}T_1}<\frac{U_2S_2}{U_1S_1}\right)=\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: probability

Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are iid continuous random variable over $(0,\infty)$,  $U_1$ and $U_2$ are iid continuous random variable over $(0,1)$. Also assume  and $T_1$, $T_1$, $S_1$ and $S_2$ are iid continuous random variable over $(0,+\infty)$. Then want to check whether the equality holds or not , $$P\left(\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}<\frac{U_2S_2+c\bar{U_2}T_2}{U_1S_1+c\bar{U_1}T_1}<\frac{U_2S_2}{U_1S_1}\right)= \frac{1}{4}$$
where $c>1$, a constant and $\bar{U}=1-U$.

Trying this problem using conditioning on variables, but could  not able to prove it.  The above expression can be written as $$P\left(\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}<\frac{U_2S_2+c\bar{U_2}T_2}{U_1S_1+c\bar{U_1}T_1}<\frac{U_2S_2}{U_1S_1}/U_1S_1<U_2S_2\right)P(U_1S_1<U_2S_2)+P\left(\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}<\frac{U_2S_2+c\bar{U_2}T_2}{U_1S_1+c\bar{U_1}T_1}<\frac{U_2S_2}{U_1S_1}/U_1S_1>U_2S_2\right)P(U_1S_1>U_2S_2)$$
And we also can use $P(U_1S_1>U_2S_2)=1/2$ but I am struck at when dealing with the $\frac{U_2S_2+c\bar{U_2}T_2}{U_1S_1+c\bar{U_1}T_1}$.

Comment: Maybe you can use that $U_2S_2 + c\bar{U}_2T_2$ lies on the connecting line between $S_2$ and $cT_2$ and a point on this line is between $Z_1$ and $U_2S_2$ if the weight $\bar{U}_2 > U_2$ and $cT_2 < S_2$ and of course $Z_1 < U_2S_2$. But that's just an idea, don't know if it gets you anywere. The thought for the denominator is the same.

Comment: @Daniel..Thanks for attention. I am not getting the idea properly but it seems interesting. Could you please explain it a little bit.

Comment: Puh, that's very tough without any information about the distributions. Also I'm sorry, but my thoughts earlier were wrong. It's easy to see that $U_2S_2 + (1-U_2)cT_2 \geq U_2S_2$ for any $T_2 \in (0, \infty)$, so there is no way that there is a line between $S_2$ and $cT_2$ that lies completely between $Z_1$ and $U_2S_2$. Maybe you can rewrite the event with intersections and then use the unindependence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try cross multiplying. I don't think there is a need to condition.

Comment: Sorry...I have made serious mistake in the question. Now I corrected it.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. _Now_ it makes sense. I would still cross multiply first. Then, yes a next reasonable step is to condition. What did you attempt? You might not be far off.

Comment: I am stucking when dealing with $\frac{U_2S_2+c\bar{U_2}T_2}{U_1S_1+c\bar{U_1}T_1}$. Added it in the question